# NextJS how to get [name] from path /app/books/[name]/edit

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have an `/app/books/` page with all the books, `/app/books/[name]` with the selected book and `/app/books/[name]/edit` is a page for editing `name` book. How in `page.tsx` inside `edit` directory can I get the `name` of the book? Currently I think about using `usePathname()` and split it by I hope there is more `nextjs` type solution

Comment: have you read this? https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// typescript
export default function EditBook({
  params,
}: {
  params: {
    name: string
  }
}) {
  return <span>edit book {params.name} </span>
}

// javascript
export default function EditBook({ params }) {
  return <span>edit book {params.name} </span>
}
```